# Laravel Application usages more than 90% CPU usages for 100 concurrent users with high server configuration

Tags: php, linux, apache, laravel-5

I have migrated the existing application from core php to laravel framework. But the laravel application usage more than 90% cpu for the 100 concurrent users but the same application developed in core php usages the 5% cpu load only for the same load.

Then I have created one sample 'helloworld' application in laravel for load testing and result is the same. 
I have tested the laravel application using load testing tool siege, hits url 'siege www.mysite.com/helloworld -c250 -t20s' for 250 concurrent users (duration 20 sec) and still cpu load reaches more than 90% (linux centos 7.5 8 core 8 gb ram apache).

Also tested the core php file 'helloworld.php' using same load testing tool ('siege www.mysite.com/helloworld.php -c250 -t20s') but CPU usage not exceeded even 5%.

- I am using the latest php version ie 7.2
- linux server centos 7.5 8 core 8 gb ram
- apache
- Also tried the varnish http cache
- laravel version 5.4 (also tried the 5.6 but the result is the same)

I don't know where is the issue I have tried everything but still not resolved the issue. Is there anything missing in the configuration on the server or in the coding end. Please suggest.

Comment: are you using php opcache?

Comment: Yes, its enable too.

Comment: Core php app/url works extremely fast with minimum cpu usage as compare to laravel. The main issue is cpu usage.

Comment: Then you need to debug code using profiler to find problem otherwise its difficult to solve it.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @JasminMistry, I have check the simple hello world application no extra code but still the same issue in the case of concurrent users

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16897997/laravel-artisan-queues-high-cpu-usage/25499624#25499624

Comment: @BilalAhmed, I haven't set up any queues. So this is not the case.